# What did permissioned blockchain solve?

Tags: blockchain

Public Blockchain solved Byzantine Generals' Problem.

However, what did Permissioned Blockchain solve??
Can that be sovled only by blockchain??

It seems to me that, what permissioned blockchain solved can also be sovled by simple p2p network and voting consensus system without any hash algorithm.

Comment: --additional explanation--
I think that blockchain is using hash algorithm to make the situation that "Data is created by decent amount of cost".
In the permissioned blockchain, however, cost is not necessary to create block. 
What does hash algorithm do in permissioned blockchain ?

Comment: It serves the same purpose as the a commit hash in git-- it's there to help maintain data integrity.

Comment: It makes sense.
Blockchain data structure and git data structure are very similar as you say.

So, permitted blockchain has nothing new technology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockchain (Bitcoin) was invented to achieve consensus in distributed, public networks, where some participants might not be trusted to act honestly, see [Bitcoin whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf).

Permissioned networks already have a consensus mechanism (by requiring permission to join and participate), so using a blockchain adds little or no value to the operation of the system, other than a mechanism to verify data integrity (as you've pointed out, could already be done easily before blockchain was created).

Using a chain of blocks is not the innovation, the innovation is combining it with proof-of-work to achieve consensus in a distributed, public, trustless network.

Answer (score 0):

Permissioned and Closed Blockchains are aspiring to implement verifiable data structures such as verifiable credentials, verifiable logs, verifiable certificates, verifiable assets etc. leveraging leader based ( PBFT, ABFT, IBFT, RAFT) and randomness based protocols ( PoET ). The closed networks created by these permissioned blockchains are known as consortiums which tries to control the information flow in a distributed database. Consortiums, Membership Services, Distributed FIle Systems, Distributed Databases, Secure Data Marketplaces, Verified Organization Networks etc. are some of the value propositions of permissioned and closed blockchains.